# Drush installation - setting symlink to /usr/local/bin/drush is a must?

Tags: drush

Refering to https://www.drupal.org/node/2132447, I would like to install Drush in `/usr/slocal/abc` directory, and I tried the following steps:

```
$ cd /usr/slocal/abc
$ wget --quiet -O - http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drush-7.x-5.9.tar.gz
$ tar -zxf drush-7.x-5.9.tar.gz
$ ln -s /usr/slocal/abc/drush/drush /usr/local/bin/drush
```

Then, I got this error:

> ln: creating symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/drush': Permission denied

I asked my system admin who said that the company policy does not allow to install stuff into `/usr/local/bin`.

I've searched many installation guides, all of them requires to create a symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/drush' in order to run Drush. Is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: What Linux OS are you running?

Comment: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer the question directly, but a preferred and much simpler way to install Drush, is to install it through the Composer.

## Installing Composer

See [Composer's website](https://getcomposer.org/download/) for greater detail.

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
# If the above code fails, use this one.
# php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
sed -i '1i export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' $HOME/.bashrc source $HOME/.bashrc
```

## Installing Drush

See [Drush instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#user-content-installupdate---a-global-drush-for-all-projects) for greater detail.

To install Drush 6:

```
composer global require drush/drush:6.*
```

Or to install Drush 7:

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

## Update

Per @[leekit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/39386), he was able to solve his original issue by substituting the symbolic link with `export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/drush:/usr/local/bin"`. For that and other alternatives, refer to step **3** of **Install - Manual**, on [Drush instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#user-content-install---manual).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Finally, refer to https://github.com/drush-ops/drush#user-content-installupdate---a-global-drush-for-all-projects, I tried using $PATH to configure my system to recognize where Drush resides: `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/slocal/abc/drush`, then run `source .bashrc`. It works now!

Comment: You're right. That would be an alternative for a symbolic link.

Comment: What exactly is usr/slocal? Is it a custom bin dir per user?

Comment: @murraybiscuit Since it is /usr/slocal, it is not a user directory; it is a directory inside the root directory of the boot disk.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to install Drush with Homebrew which is the route I usually go down. https://www.drupal.org/node/954766